# php page doesn't rendering when connect to database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making simple php web page, using php5, mysql, Nginx.

when connect to database, it suddenly freeze, and render nothing to browser..
my php code is this.

```
<?php
  $host = 'localhost';
  $user = 'root';
  $password = '123456';
  $db_name = 'test';

  $link = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db_name);

  if($link->connect_errno) {
    echo "<script>alert('Connection Error....')</script>";
  }

  if($link) {
    echo "<script>alert('Successfully connected!');</script>";
  }
?>
```

(lib/connect_db.php)

```
<?php
   include './lib/connect_db.php';

   $create_user_query = 'CREATE TABLE ...';
   $admin_user_query = 'INSERT INTO ....';
   $create_widget_query = 'CREATE TABLE ...';

   if($link->query($create_user_query) === TRUE) {
     echo "<script>alert('Success!')</script>";
   }

   $link->close();
?>
```

(init.php)

index.php also include './lib/connect_db.php', it is OK. but init.php always causing problem.

p.s. when I edited init.php to

```
<script>alert('...');</script>
<?php
  ...
?>
```

it doesn't call alert();

Comment: `include '.lib/connect_db.php';` ? or `include 'lib/connect_db.php';`

Answer (score 0):

you have syntax error you missing  **$** before variable  in (lib/connect_db.php)

```
  include '.lib/connect_db.php';

   $create_user_query = 'CREATE TABLE ...';
   $admin_user_query = 'INSERT INTO ....';
   $create_widget_query = 'CREATE TABLE ...';

   if($link->query($create_user_query) === TRUE) {
     echo "<script>alert('Success!')</script>";
   }

   $link->close();
```